# MongoDB Aggregate of 120M documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've a system that records entries by action. There're more than 120M of them and I want to group them with aggregate by id_entry. The structure is as the following :

```
entry
{
    id_entry: ObjectId(...),
    created_at: Date(...),
    action: {object},
}
```

When I try to do an aggregate by id_entry and grouping its actions it takes more than 3h to finish :

```
db.entry.aggregate([
{ '$match': {'created_at': { $gte:ISODate("2016-02-02"), $lt:ISODate("2016-02-03")}}},
{ '$group': {
    '_id' :{'id_entry': '$id_entry'},
    actions: {
        $push: '$action'
    }
}}])
```

But in that range of days there's only around ~4M documents. (id_entry and created_at has indexes)

What im I doing wrong in the aggregate? How can I group 3-4M documents to join them by id_entry in less than 3h?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have index on `created_at`? How long takes this query: `db.entry.find({'created_at': { $gte:ISODate("2016-02-02"), $lt:ISODate("2016-02-03")}})` ?

Comment: Hi @DmitryZyr , thank you for answering. That query took 0.057s and retrieves 2.703.103 documents. I think that the big issue is on grouping 2,7M documents...

Answer (score 0):

To speed up your particular query, you need an index on the `created_at` field.

However, the overall performance of the aggregation will also depend on your hardware specification (among other things).

If you find the query's performance to be less than what you require, you can either:

- Create a [pre-aggregated report](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/) (essentially a document that contains the aggregated data you require, updated every time a new data is inserted), or
- Utilize [sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/) to spread your data to more servers.

If you need to run this aggregation query all the time, a pre-aggregated report allows you to have an extremely up-to-date aggregated report of your data that is accessible using a simple `find()` query.

The tradeoff is that for every insertion, you will also need to update the pre-aggregated document to reflect the current state of your data. However, this is a relatively small tradeoff compared to having to run long/complex aggregation query that could interfere with your day-to-day operation.

One caveat with the aggregation framework is: once the aggregation pipeline encounters a `$group` or a `$project` stage, no index can be used. This is because MongoDB index are tied to how the documents are stored physically. Grouping and projecting transform the documents to a state where the document does not have a physical representation in disk anymore.